# read JSON data sent using post in jquery with laravel framework

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have this codes,

```
var obj = '{"items":[{"Code":"c101","Description":"Car"}]}';
$.post('get-items',obj,function(){

});
```

I used this code,

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

Because I cant get the POST Data that is sent.
Using the above code, I get the raw POST Data.

How can I read data sent without using file_get_contents('php://input')?
Because I can't use file_get_contents('php://input').

Here is my Laravel controller function,

```
public function getItems()
{
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if(isset($data))
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to get the data sent in PHP?

Comment: I don't get this. We are talking about the PHP part or the js part? In PHP `$_POST['items']` doesn't work? Did you put json header on top in your PHP file `header('Content-Type: application/json');`? How do you handle this ajax request in PHP?

Comment: Yes melvin.. @marios, no. i didnt put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 5.3 expects input to be sent in array format https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#retrieving-input

**Request sent through jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://weburl.com/api/user/create',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'user': user},
        success: function(data) {
            this.setState({data: data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(null, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
    });
```

**Laravel UserController::create**

```
public function create(Request $request)
{

    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $request->input('user.name');
    $user->email = $request->input('user.email');
    $user->password = $request->input('user.password');

    $user->save();

    return response($user, 201);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Laravel 5.2 controller's method you could do this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $items = $request->input('items');

    return [
        'error' => false,
        'items' => $items
    ];
}
```

Comment: How can I do it in Laravel Controller function?

Comment: I tried to change my whole function. The result is {error: false, items: null}

Comment: In your network XHR tab in chrome dev tools is your items object in the request payload? I mean js sends items object to php as wanted?

Comment: Can you explain? I don't get it.

Comment: I mean are we sure that your js works? Does it really send data to PHP?